# How to remove a linebreak from getRandom?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and Selenium. I am choosing a random line from a txt file with this code:

```
with open('surnames.txt') as fr:
    surnames = fr.readlines()
    surname = random.choice(surnames) if surnames else None
```

The problem is that Python always adds the line break so if I write:

```
print(surname + '@gmail.com')
```

This gets exported:

```
Peter
@gmail.com
```

But I want it to be exported as following:

```
Peter@gmail.com
```

Do you maybe have a solution?

Comment: This will work out `surnames = fr.read().splitlines()` that will eliminate `\n` for new lines while reading text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(surname.rstrip() + '@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove line break by simply replacing the character: `surname.replace('\n', '')`.